# Multicolumn index logic on PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I've read that the columns used an index on `WHERE` listed should be ordered from left to right.
and if one of the columns (from the first of the list) is not used, index scanning should not be applied.

I've created an index

`CREATE INDEX on students (status, control_id);`

So based on the statement (or what I understood) above, the index will not be applied if the query would only be on `control_id`

But why does it seem that when I query

`EXPLAIN select * from students where control_id = 2`, the index scan is applied.

Maybe I misunderstood this. Please help me understand.

Thank you!

Comment: The index can indeed be used by Postgres, but it's not as efficient as if it was when the column is the leading column

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh, interesting. I would be interested to see an example of that; it is new to me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh >_< that explains why it still uses the created index.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) "*A multicolumn B-tree index can be used with query conditions that involve any subset of the index's columns, but the index is most efficient when there are constraints on the leading (leftmost) columns*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh, I see. This refers to cases where the *whole* index is scanned, like using an index only scan for an aggregate query.